# How to allow access for only United Kingdom and a second country

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I'd like to restrict the allowed IPs to UK and a second country, say Brazil or whatever other one.

I did find an answer, but the link to the tutorials are not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below .htaccess can helpyou.

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 11.305.12.0/29
allow from ....
</LIMIT>
```

Just give ipaddess ranges of UK & Second country in the allow from part

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299795/3853188):

Updated answer

My best idea would be.To handle it in the application level rather than webserver level.you can easily get country name using the ip-address which can get from webrequst If its UK or second country then you can let him see you main page or else you can redirect to a page that says the access protection available to the countris

Comment: Thanks Naga R. I did see the source. I uinderstand it, but I don´t get how to know what ranges I must use for a particular country.

Comment: Thanks Naga. I'll do some experiments with the info.

Comment: Here is a webservice aka API that does it...http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?op=GetGeoIP

Comment: @Sergio - Any improvements so far ?

Comment: I have had horrible problems with my internet provider. Right now the connection is fallin down nine times per hour, so I need to fix that. Cheers

Comment: @Sergio - I'd really appreciate if you share the solution so that we can look for some other ways and fine tune it.

Comment: Sorry, Naga. It was a bad year start. Technical problems, first, and serious health problems came to ruin the last months. I did check it as the right answer. Thanks and cheers.